# What does IntPtr.Zero mean in System.Drawing.Graphics

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, intptr, word-addins

I need to get the exact meaning of IntPtr.Zero in below function.
I used this function for convert word document text range position pixel value to WPF unit value.

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)
```

That normally said to pass the handle,but I didn't get it.

Answer (score 6):

`Graphics.FromHwnd` method is used to create a `Graphics` object from the specified handler of a window.

When you pass `IntPtr.Zero` as parameter you are creating a `Graphics` from the windows desktop that allow you draw directly in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

`IntPtr` is a platform specific way to represent a handle or pointer. On 32 bit systems a pointer is 32 bits wide, whilst on a 64 bit system it is 64 bits wide. This type exists to hide these differences from you.

[IntPtr.Zero](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.zero(v=vs.110).aspx) represents a handle or pointer whose values is 0 (essentially null). You can use it in places where the API expects a Windows API style handle, such as in the `FromHwnd` call in your example. In the Windows API a HWND is a window handle, where null indicates "no window". To pass this via C# you use [IntPtr.Zero](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.zero(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: *"In the Windows API a HWND is a window handle, where null indicates "no window"."* - There is no such convention in the Windows API. Whenever a `HWND` argument is optional, it carries specific semantics. Since `System.Graphics.Drawing` wraps GDI+, which is implemented in terms of GDI, I would assume, that this retrieves an object representing the entire screen, although this is not specifically documented.