# Graphics's dpi not refreshing at runtime in c#

Tags: c#, graphics, scale, dpi

I am always checking `Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).DpiX` value and scaling my component with this value. But when I change my scale rate on "Windows Display Settings" while the application is running, Graphics still looks same. Dpi value could not updated at runtime.

Scaling is 100% at the beginning > Application has been started > DpiX is 98 > Scaling changed to 150% > DpiX is still 98, but it should be 144.

Is there any way to find current dpi or scale rate?

Comment: You handle is always IntPtr.Zero.  I think you want to get the handle number from the control object like this.Handle which would be the form handle.

Comment: Still same with this.Handle

Comment: The control you are using to view the image probably isn't getting refresh.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I refreshed the control but nothing changed. I don't want to restart the app to get updated dpi.

Comment: Need to see the code where you adding image to the control.

Comment: @jdweng `Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)` means getting the Windows Desktop Graphics.

Comment: @JokeHuang : Where does it say the you can pass a zero pointer to the method?

Comment: @jdweng https://stackoverflow.com/a/37075887/3907561